# Problems implementing touch events in JavaScript so it works in WebView in Android

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, webview, touch-event

So I have this little project and it works very good in browser, you can see it on a [temporary free hosting](http://laplacegfv.000webhostapp.com/).

And now I wanted to optimize the code so it works on Android also, but I'm having problem with touch events.

So the code I had for my `mouseup`, `mousedown` events in JavaScript is this:

```
function InjectIntoHtml() { 
  ...SomeCode....

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', clickDown);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', clickUp);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchStart', clickDown);
  canvas.addEventListener('touchEnd', clickUp);

  function clickDown() {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', handleClick);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', handleClick);
  }

  function clickUp() {
    canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleClick);
    canvas.removeEventListener("touchmove", handleClick);
  }
}
```

And now I added `touchStart` and `touchEnd`, where it's supposed to be, as you can see, but still on touch events all I get is a dragging scroll in my `WebView`, I also tried to open it in browser and also nothing, touches just scroll the page. I tried disabling the scroll in my `WebView` but also nothing.

Here is the code from my `MainActivity.java` (code is in `onCreate`):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("http://laplacegfv.000webhostapp.com/");
```

Comment: i managed to get it t work, it's touchstart not touchStart...

but on computer i can mouse click down and drag the mouse to draw my borders, but on phone it's not working

Comment: also, when i don't disable scroll of webview, touch events arent working, and if i disable scroll well.. i can't scroll.. i ran out of ideas...